# What's the difference between ways in assigning a pointer?

Tags: c++

Thank you for checking my question. I just encountered a really fundamental problem when I am implementing a BST, that is "what the difference in different approaches to assign a pointer?" We all know assign a point can use:

```
int *p, q;
p = &q;
```

Or:

```
int *p, *q;
p = q;
```

They should be the same. But in my case below, they working totally different:

```
template <typename T>
void Tree<T>::_insert(TreeNode<T>*& tree, const T& value, const unsigned& key)
{
//  TreeNode<T> node(value, key);
//  if(tree == nullptr) tree = &node;
    TreeNode<T> *node = new TreeNode<T>(value, key);
    if(tree == nullptr) tree = node;

    else if(key < tree->index) _insert(tree->left, value, key);
    else if(key > tree->index) _insert(tree->right, value, key);
    else if(key == tree->index) std::cerr << "_insert: repeating key" << std::endl;
}
```

Using the first way (noted one), the function won't assign tree equal to node, while the second way works fine.

So, is this my fault write, or they naturally different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please notice in the first case:

```
//  TreeNode<T> node(value, key);
//  if(tree == nullptr) tree = &node;
```

`node` is an object allocated on **stack**.

While in the second case

```
TreeNode<T> *node = new TreeNode<T>(value, key);
if(tree == nullptr) tree = node;
```

`node` is allocated on **heap**.

The difference is that once `_insert` function returns, its stack frame is poped, and all local variables/objects becomes invalid, as a result, you'll have memory errors.

Comment: Thank you for your response, really appreciate it. So, if I understand correctly, the reason I got error is because variable declared in heap will be freed when it exceeds the scope, so, in the first case, "node" will be freed and the pointer "tree" will be reseted to "nullptr", right?

Comment: @XiangyuZhang No, memory allocated in heap will not be freed unless you explicitly doing so (that's why you didn't have problem in second case). For the first case, pointer "tree" will not be reset to "nullptr" once the stack frame of _insert is popped, it'll be still remain what it was, but since _insert() has returned, what "tree" points to is just random memory (stack frame of following function calls will overwrite the allocated stack memory), dereferencing/accessing the "tree" pointer is certainly to be problematic.

Comment: @XiangyuZhang Maybe it's helpful in looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#STACK-FRAME

Answer (score 3):

No, the two ways should not be the same:

- The first assignment `p = &q` is perfectly valid, because `q` is the actual object in memory, and `p` is a pointer to it
- The second assignment `p = q` assigns an unitialized pointer `q` to `p`, which is undefined behavior.

That is why the two implementations are different.

If you would like to assign `q` to `p`, the `q` itself needs to be assigned first. For example, you could assign `new int` to it:

```
int *p, *q = new int;
p = q;
```

However, in this case you might as well assign `new int` directly to `p`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *p, q;
p = &q;
```

This means that p now has the address at which the integer q is stored in the memory.

```
int *p, *q;
p = q;
```

In this you are copying the address stored in the pointer q to p.